# CPLEX, C coding

Tags: c, linux, cplex

I am coding in C an optimization problem on linux. I am using CPLEX to solve this optimization problem. 
I wrote my code and everything, but when i'm trying to compile in the terminal, I am getting such errors:

etc.... I am trying to change in my code the CPX to CPXX but still
I have a 64-bit machine
model.c is the name of my C file.`model.c:(.text+0x115c): undefined reference to "CPXnewrows"
model.c:(.text+0x121b): undefined reference to "CPXchgcoeflist"
model.c:(.text+0xd62): undefined reference to "CPXnewcols"`
Please any help would be more than grateful!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are linker errors.  You need to link the CPLEX library with `model.c`.
[This link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r3/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/Optimization_Studio/_pubskel/ps_gscplex1295.html) might have some applicable information on how to do this on Linux.

Comment: Thank you! it worked cause I had an error in the cplex path!!